# CSS filter property disabling fixed position on navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I made my navigation bar and positioned it (fixed), and it works fine. I was able to scroll down and all. As soon has I added filter (brightness) to it the image on my page, the navigation bar disappeared. I have tried using pseudo-elements and setting the position (absolute/relative), I set the filter property to the container of the child element of the image, it still didn't work. Can someone help me on how to have my navigation bar display on fixed position and still have the image filtered. Thanks in Advance.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #ff6600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  filter: brightness(60%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Brand</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">services</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="title-image">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599546824091-f49550ce8cbc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
</div>
```

**[`JSfiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/stephenmiles08/45fa7x8e/365/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add z-index to your nav element as follow

```css
nav{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index:999;
}
nav ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
.navbar-brand{
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a{
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover{
  color: #ff6600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title-image img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  filter: brightness(60%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Brand</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">Home</a>
     </li>   
     <li>
       <a href="#">About</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">services</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="title-image">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599546824091-f49550ce8cbc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
</div>
```

Comment: Even the `z-index` of 1 would be enough in this particular case.

Comment: Yes of course but as it is a navbar it is better to set a height value instead of a very low one.

Answer (score 0):

The navbar didn't disappear, it is just beneath the image. To have it in front, you should use `z-index: 10;` (or any value greater than 0).

See more at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

In addition, keep in mind that your image - or any element after your navbar - will be positioned on top of your page. May be you'll want to let the equivalent of the navbar height as space before any content.

Comment: equivalent of the navbar height as space...sorry i don't understand, how do i do that?

Comment: You could either add this space as padding-top of the parent element of the navbar, or add this space as margin-top of the following element of the navbar